# How to avoid multiple paths for a canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am currently developing an Android app which allows the user to plot a graph by hand drawing on a canvas. Now I want to make sure that the graph consists of only one path. Is there a way to implement an object that lays on the canvas (for example a mouse or whatever) which can be controlled by the user in order to sketch the graph?
So the user should touch the object and move it. If he wants to extend the path, he just can touch it again and proceed.
Sorry if it's not clear what I want to achieve, the screenshots may help.
Screenshot 1 shows, which type of graphs I want to avoid, while the second screenshot shows how the graphs should look like (don't consider the green circles, they're just indicating turning points)

[image: I want to avoid drawings like this(with several paths)]
[image: Only graphs like this should be able to draw, only one path]

Comment: What stops you from doing just that?  Draw a circle at the end of the previous path, do hit checking and only accept input if the pointer down action occurs inside the circle, and append the points from that to the previous data?

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to render the circle constantly with the path, do you know how i could achieve that?